# Validation not working on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried a form validation using `jquery.validate.min.js`.

When i click submit button that will show the empty required fields with red border. Problem is page was loading while click submit button.

Validation not working. Don't know where is the issue. Thanks in advance.

```js
jQuery(".submit-form").validate({
               rules: {
                   fname: {
                       required: true,
                   },
                   lname: {
                       required: true,
                   },
                   phone: {
                       required: true,
                   },
                   mail: {
                       required: true,
                       mail: true
                   },
                   subjct: {
                       required: true,
                   },
                   message: {
                       required: true,
                   },
               },
               submitHandler: function (form) {
                   var postData = $(form).serializeArray();
                   var result = {};
                   $.each(postData, function () {
                       result[this.name] = this.value;
                   });
                   return false;
               },
               invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
                   $('form input,textarea').each(function () {
                       if ($(this).val() == "") {
                           $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
                       } else {
                           $(this).css('border', '1px solid #d2d2d2');
                       }
                   });
               },
               errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                   return true;
               }
           });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form class="submit-form" method="post">
                        <div class="row input-row-common">
                            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-2 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <input type="name" class="input-common fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <input type="name" class="input-common" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row input-row-common">
                            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-2 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <input type="name" class="input-common" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Number">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <input type="email" class="input-common" name="mail" placeholder="Email ID">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row input-row-common">
                            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" class="input-txtarea"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row input-row-common">
                            <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="send message">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-8"></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this answer

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
          $("#submit-form").validate({
              rules: {
                  fname: {
                      required: true,
                  },
                  lname: {
                      required: true,
                  },
                  phone: {
                      required: true,
                  },
                  mail: {
                      required: true,
                      mail: true
                  },
                  subjct: {
                      required: true,
                  },
                  message: {
                      required: true,
                  },
              },
              submitHandler: function (form) {
                  var postData = $(form).serializeArray();
                  var result = {};
                  $.each(postData, function () {
                      result[this.name] = this.value;
                  });
                  return false;
              },
              invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
                  $('form input,textarea').each(function () {
                      if ($(this).val() == "") {
                          $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
                      } else {
                          $(this).css('border', '1px solid #d2d2d2');
                      }
                  });
              },
              errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                  return true;
              }
          });
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="submit-form" method="post">
                       <div class="row input-row-common">
                           <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-2 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                               <input type="name" class="input-common fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required />
                           </div>

                           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                               <input type="name" class="input-common" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2"></div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="row input-row-common">
                           <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-2 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                               <input type="name" class="input-common" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Number" required />
                           </div>

                           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                               <input type="email" class="input-common" name="mail" placeholder="Email ID" required />
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2"></div>
                       </div>

                       <div class="row input-row-common">
                           <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                               <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" class="input-txtarea" required /></textarea>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2"></div>
                       </div>

                       <div class="row input-row-common">
                           <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                               <input type="submit" class="submit" value="send message" />
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-8"></div>
                       </div>
                   </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

SubmitHandler is not working because there is a mistake in your code :

```
mail: {
   required: true,
   mail: true
},
```

it should be

```
mail: {
       required: true,
       email: true
    },
```

and try using alert in submitHandler i am sure you will get it, like

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
                    alert('submit');
                   return false;
               },
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/ACdtX/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `preventDefault()` to prevent automatic page loading while form submitting.

```
$(".submit-form").submit(function(e) {

    console.log("> I am e.preventDefault ");
    e.preventDefault();                     # add this line

    }).validate({
         rules: {
               fname: {
                   required: true,
               },
               lname: {
                   required: true,
               },
               phone: {
                   required: true,
               },
               mail: {
                   required: true,
                   mail: true
               },
               subjct: {
                   required: true,
               },
               message: {
                   required: true,
               },
           },
           submitHandler: function (form) {
               console.log(" In submitHandler!!");  # to make sure code is executing

               var postData = $(form).serializeArray();
               var result = {};
               $.each(postData, function () {
                   result[this.name] = this.value;
               });
               return false;
           },
           invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {

               console.log(">>> In invalidHandler!!");    # add this line

               $('form input,textarea').each(function () {
                   if ($(this).val() == "") {
                       $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
                   } else {
                       $(this).css('border', '1px solid #d2d2d2');
                   }
               });
           },
           errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
               return true;
           }
       });
```

Comment: Page is loading still now or, validation is not working ?

Comment: Do you see any error in `Console` (Chrome Developer Tools)?

Comment: Can you add `console.log()` in `submitHandler` & `invalidHandler` func to make sure Plugin is triggering and code is executing ? Edited my answer.

Comment: Tried that.. Event was not triggering

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code and try.

```
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

        <form class="submit-form" method="post">
                    <div class="row input-row-common">
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-2 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <input type="name" class="input-common fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <input type="name" class="input-common" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row input-row-common">
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-2 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <input type="name" class="input-common" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Number">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <input type="email" class="input-common" name="mail" placeholder="Email ID">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row input-row-common">
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" class="input-txtarea"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row input-row-common">
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <input type="submit" class="submit" value="send message">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-8"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>




                <script>
                    jQuery(".submit-form").validate({
                           rules: {
                               fname: {
                                   required: true,
                               },
                               lname: {
                                   required: true,
                               },
                               phone: {
                                   required: true,
                               },
                               mail: {
                                   required: true,
                                   email: true
                               },
                               subjct: {
                                   required: true,
                               },
                               message: {
                                   required: true,
                               },
                           },
                           submitHandler: function (form) {
                               /*var postData = $(form).serializeArray();
                               console.log("psots data  using ajax or normal submit"+postData);*/

                               form.submit();
                           },
                       });
                </script>
```